# Scanning documents in UWP and WASM

Tags: uwp, uno-platform

my boss told me a week ago that we need to be able to list the Scanner Devices availables and select one of them for scanning documents in UNO PLATFORM. We mainly need this working for Wasm and Uwp. I tried to use Windows.Devices.Scanners and Windows.Devices.Enumeration because I read this microsoft doc https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/blob/docs/windows-apps-src/devices-sensors/scan-from-your-app.md (tried it in an UNO project and UWP project):

```
private async void OnScannerAdded(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation deviceInfo)
        {
            await
            MainPage.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
                  Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                  () =>
                  {
                      MainPage.Current.NotifyUser(String.Format("Scanner with device id {0} has been added", deviceInfo.Id), NotifyType.StatusMessage);

                 // search the device list for a device with a matching device id
                 ScannerDataItem match = FindInList(deviceInfo.Id);

                 // If we found a match then mark it as verified and return
                 if (match != null)
                      {
                          match.Matched = true;
                          return;
                      }

                 // Add the new element to the end of the list of devices
                 AppendToList(deviceInfo);
                  }
            );
        }
```

But when i copy the code for list all the scanner devices I get some errors and I'm not able to build the project. Specifically these two lines:

MainPage.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync and the other one that calls Current from MainPage (It shows : mainpage does not contain a definition for current.)

The other one is ScannerDataItem match = FindInList(deviceInfo.Id); (Can't find the ScannerDataItem Class even though i write the two usings the doc specify at the start of the readme).

My boss told me that he did this years ago with Twain and WIA but i can't find any info for Visual Studio 2019 and the nugets packages that use Twain almost haven't any documentation.

It's the first time i ask something here, if you need more code or something just say it. I need to make it work, thanks.

Comment: Can you replace the `MainPage.Current.Dispatcher` by `Dispatcher` and see if this helps ?

Comment: @JérômeLaban Done but the MainPage.Current.NotifyUser can't be NotifyUser and the parameter NotifyType.StatusMessage says "does not exists in the current context

Comment: It's likely that you're missing code from the original sample you used to get this code from. Looks like the docs are build from this sample: https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/blob/21cb9b6bc0da3b234c5854ecac449cb3bd261f29/Official%20Windows%20Platform%20Sample/Scan%20Runtime%20API%20Sample/%5BC%23%5D-Scan%20Runtime%20API%20Sample/C%23/common/ScannerContext.cs

Comment: @JérômeLaban Tried to implement this class but all the properties that come after MainPage.Current shows the same error and it doesn't recognize the Dispatcher  if i put it without MainPage.Current

Comment: Take a look at the sample's MainPage, you could know what is MainPage.Current and what is MainPage.Current.NotifyUser. Here: https://github.com/microsoftarchive/msdn-code-gallery-microsoft/blob/21cb9b6bc0da3b234c5854ecac449cb3bd261f29/Official%20Windows%20Platform%20Sample/Scan%20Runtime%20API%20Sample/%5BC%23%5D-Scan%20Runtime%20API%20Sample/C%23/MainPage.xaml.cs

Answer (score 0):

The NotifyUser method is a customized method, which always is called to Update UI to Show notification message. Generally, this method is called from within the individual scenario XAML pages on the instance of MainPage that's returned from the static **Current** field. NotifyUser takes a parameter of type NotifyType. You could find the source code of NotifyUser method [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/SharedContent/cs/MainPage.xaml.cs).

As for the ScannerDataItem class, it is also a customized class, which is used to store scanner device information, you need to define properties for scanner device.